# How to disable export of survey list in SP 2013?

Tags: permissions, export, survey-list

Is there a permission setting that prevents users from exporting data from a survey list? I have found articles saying to disable the "Use Client Integration Features" on a custom permission level.

After trying this, users were still able to export data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Items is the permission which give the export to excel access.

In the "View only" permission, "View Versions" is ticked but "Open Items" is not. I think this is the difference here. I managed to get the "Export to excel" button to be disabled by making an exact copy of the "View only" permission by clicking the "Copy Permission Level" button at the bottom.

Other method is hide the button from ribbon.
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010general.aspx?ID=96755209-1381-4b4e-8c70-899519132af5

Comment: I could never get any permissions specific setting to work with SP2013. From what I found the survey list was carried over from 2007. I ended up writing a script to hide these actions based on user group.